Is the answer given in the option wrong?
The question is

"An Object moves along a straight line.  The graph illustrates how the acceleration of the object changes with time.  The direction of the motion of the object changed only once, at time $t$. Which portions of the graph represents the object moving with increasing speed?


I Tried this question, since acceleration is positive in all the portions, velocity will also be increasing and hence the speed, so all portions (P,Q,R and S) represents the object moving with increasing speed.  But in the answer key it is mentioned as R and S only, am I doing something wrong? or the answer sheet is wrong... kindly help.
Or as the object moves in one direction until time t, it has negative velocity but increasing which means the speed is decreasing and after t the speed is increasing because the object travels in another direction (which they conventionally took as positive direction)
NOTE: This is not my homework or something

"This is not my homework or something" Whether the question was actual homework is irrelevant.

The answer sheet is correct. You are ignoring the statement “The direction of the motion of the object changed only once, at time t.” That means that the velocity was zero at time t. So before time t the positive acceleration reduced the speed, and only after time t did it begin to increase the speed.
